# Jupyter notebook download as error nbconvert failed: no filter named 'escape_html_keep_quotes'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, latex, jupyter, miktex

Trying to get my download functionality in Jupyter Notebook to work.

I installed some templates earlier to try to deal with text getting cut off after downloading to PDF but then it seems to have screwed up something with the setup.

I tried uninstalling miktex, pandoc and the templates I was trying to use.  Still running into this error whenever I choose download as for anything:

nbconvert failed: no filter named 'escape_html_keep_quotes'

Not sure what could be problem or even where to start troubleshooting this.  Some suggestions or solution would be great!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The following statement solved the issue.

```
pip install -U nbconvert==5.6.1 --user
```

You may need to restart your kernel after installation.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this problem yesterday.  Here's what ultimately ended up working for me.

- pandoc version < 3.X.X, I ended up using version 2.19.2 and installed using the .msi installer provided.  https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/tag/2.19.2
  [image]
- nbconvert version 7.4.0 (latest) installed via pip install
  [image]

Instead of using the jupyter GUI download button, I used the CLI tool which appears to run fine if you have a latex backend setup, I'm using Miktex (https://miktex.org/download).

The following command in the virtual environment containing nbconvert produces a nice pdf into the directory where the command is called.

```
jupyter nbconvert MyNotebookFilename.ipynb --to pdf
```